# my fancybox opens if I use "id" but dont opens if I use "class"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have a article with content, and I also have a link to a div, to open a fancybox with that div content, like this:

```
<p>Content of the news<a class="fancybox" href="#show">See more</a></p>
```

Now I wanted to pass my div #show where I have the content that will appear in fancybox, I wanted to pass this to class like `class = "show"` and not `id = "show"` like I have.

But, when Im trying this the fancybox dont open **like this**:

```
<p>Content of the news<a class="fancybox" href=".show">See more</a></p>

<div class="show">
```

**This is my full html:**

```
<article id="loop-news">

    <h2>
    Title of the News
    </h2>
    <span>Date of the news</span> 
    <p>Content of the news<a class="fancybox" href="#show">See more</a></p>


    <div id="show-container">
        <div id="show">
            <h2>Title of the news</h2>
            <span>Date of the news</span>
            <img src="images/image1.jpg"  /> <br />  
            <p>Content of the news</p>
        </div>
    </div>


</article>
```

**My script jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        maxWidth    : 800,
        fitToView   : false,
        width       : '80%',
        height      : '80%',
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : false,    
    });
})
```

**My php:**

```
while ($readNewsResult = $readNews->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    echo '<article id="loop-news">';
            echo '<h2>';
            echo '<a href="#show" class="x" >'.$readNewsResult ['title'].'</a><br />';
            echo '</h2>';
            echo '<p>'.$readNewsResult ['content'].'<a class="fancybox" href="#show.'.$countitems++.'">See more</a></p>';

            echo '<div id="show-container">';
                echo '<div id="show.'.$countitems++.'">';
                    echo '<h2>'.$readNewsResult ['title'].'</h2>';
                    echo '<p>'.$readNewsResult ['content'].'</p>';
                 echo '</div>';    
             echo '</div>';
    echo '</article>';
}
```

Do you know why the fancybox dont open if I use class?

Comment: 1) I don't think fancybox work on classes; 2) You didn't change you id to a class on the HTML element `#show`.

Comment: Thanks for notice that, I forget to change, but I have class here and dont works! But if fancybox dont works with classes I dont know how I can solve a problem that Im having. Because Im doing a loop with php to show all articles that I have in database, and I cant repeat id´s! Do you know some way to solve this? Because if the fancybox does not work with class I´m not seeing what can I do!

Comment: I'm not an expert but maybe something like this? http://pastebin.com/8tLXnMDc

Comment: @OzzC in the php loop increment a variable like `$countitems++` and then use `'fancybox'.$countitems` as the id, like: `echo('<div id="fancybox'.$countitems">');`

Comment: Thanks for your answer FrancescoMM, I already tried one solution like yours, but the problem is that like this ('<div id="show.'.$countitems++.'">') Im always getting this error: "The requested content cannot be loaded.
Please try again later."

Comment: You have $countitems++ repeated twice, that will increment it twice. You need one $countitems=0 out of the loop. Only one $countitems++; inside the loop (put it at the beginning) and then use just $countitems everywhere else. Or simply just remove the second ++

Comment: (but I would rather put show-container out of the loop and use just one)

Comment: Thank you, but I need my fancybox content inside the loop because I have many articles to show in fancybox!

Comment: And if I use your $countitems method, it works but my css is unformatted because I have no formatting to #show1, #show2 and so on. But I can solve this problem adding a class <div id="show" class="show"> and then format the class and not the id. But a strange thing happens, when I move the mouse overr fancybox, the content of fancnybox disappears!

Comment: @OzzC Wait, you also have more elements with id="show-container" and also id="loop-news" they should all be classes or ids with $countitems appended.I don't think this explains the fancybox disappearing but it surely is not a good thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are really desperate you can always convert the class="" attribute to an id.

It is ugly and probably useless, but if you cannot change the html and cannot hack fancybox, you can

```
$(".show").first(function() {$(this).attr("id","show");});
```

Untested code, but should work, to convert the class to an id (keeps the class, adds the id)

Then `$("#show").whateverYouWant..`

More generic:

```
function addSameIdToClass(aClass) {
    $("."+aClass).first(function() {$(this).attr("id",aClass);});
}

addSameIdToClass("show");
```

This of course will work pnly with first class=".show" item

**EDIT** This seems more a PHP related question ..

I am not sure it is a good idea to have multiple class="show" items, I guess the idea of fancybox it to have one show item for many images, just put it out of the PHP loop.

If you have one show item only you can use the id, don't bother with the classes.

In case you really need more, you have to use different ids in your PHP loop:

```
$Count=0;
foreach($something as $someItem) {
    ...
    echo('<div id="show'.$Count.'">');
    ...
}
```

then inside the loop you refer to that "show" item as "#show0",  "#show1", etc..:

```
$showId='#show'.$Count;

echo('<a ... href="'.$showId.'"');
```

etc..

**EDIT 2** Cleaned a bit your PHP:

```
$countitems=0; // must init to avoid notices
while ($readNewsResult = $readNews->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $countitems++; // safer to do it here (at start or at end of loop)
    echo '<article id="loop-news'.$countitems.'" class="loop-news">';
        echo '<h2>';
            echo '<a href="#show" class="x show" >'.htmlentities($readNewsResult ['title'],ENT_COMPAT,'UTF-8').'</a><br />';
        echo '</h2>';
        echo '<p>'.htmlentities($readNewsResult ['content'],ENT_COMPAT,'UTF-8').'<a class="fancybox" href="#show.'.$countitems.'">See more</a></p>';

        echo '<div id="show-container'.$countitems.'">';
            echo '<div id="show.'.$countitems.'" class="show">';
                echo '<h2>'.htmlentities($readNewsResult ['title'],ENT_COMPAT,'UTF-8').'</h2>';
                echo '<p>'.htmlentities($readNewsResult ['content'],ENT_COMPAT,'UTF-8').'</p>';
            echo '</div>';    
        echo '</div>';
    echo '</article>';
}
```

by the way you should include $readNewsResult ['content'] and the others into an htmlentities call

htmlentities($readNewsResult['content'],ENT_COMPAT,'UTF-8')

(if UTF-8) just in case there is some < char in the database.

Comment: Not that I endorse this :)

Comment: Thank your for your answer, I did not know that was possible, maybe is the only solution! But this code you gave me I guess is not working, when I click the link to open the fancybox, my page stays a bit dark and come back soon to normal, and not open the fancybox!

Comment: @OzzC I looked at the fancybox instructions and they use a class, so something else is the problem? http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#instructions

Comment: @OzzC I edited my post to give some more details and PHP info

Comment: thank you, your solution works, but in my <acrticle id="loop-news" you also put the $counttimes variable, but I think its not necessary, is it?

Comment: @OzzC It is. you cannot have two articles with the same id. Well you can but it makes no sense and might cause problems (and you will be able to reach only one anyway).

Comment: hmm ok, thank you! but my news have id, so Im doing like this:  echo '<div id="show-container'.$countitems.'">', instead be creating a variable to count I´m using the id field of my news table! So if I want to reach only one I guess that I dont have that problem!